How to save a "expiration date or unlimited" user selection in backend dto?
I'm referring to this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/152055/mandatory-user-input-either-an-expiration-date-or-unlimited
The user can either pick an expiration date or check the option "No expiration date" which deactivates the expiration date picker.
My CertificateAssignment-Entity currently looks like this:
CertificateAssignment.kt
data class CertificateAssignmentDto(
    val uuid: UUID?,
    val certificate: CertificateDto,
    val employeeId: UUID?,
    val issueDate: LocalDate,
    val expirationDate: LocalDate?,
    val isNotExpiring: Boolean
)

I'm not really happy with the negated isNotExpiring flag. But renaming it to isExpiring and then inverting the user selection seems also to be dirty.... what could be an alternative?

Wouldn't an expirationDate with a value of null already indicate that no expiration date was chosen? You explicitly made it nullable…

@deHaar It of course depends on the usecase, but in this scenario, I would definately assume that a null expirationDate would equate with unknown, and not that it does not expire. That being said, OP, what I would personally do, is to create 2 constructors.

Assuming that the meaning of no defined expirationDate means the Certificate Assignment never expires, how about this:
data class CertificateAssignmentDto(
    val uuid: UUID?,
    val certificate: CertificateDto,
    val employeeId: UUID?,
    val issueDate: LocalDate,
    val expirationDate: LocalDate?,
) {
    val isNotExpiring = (expirationDate == null)
    val isExpiring = (expirationDate != null)
}

with two derived variables that offer the caller a choice of whichever logic they prefer.
